# Collapse menu bootstrap positioning badly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my menu responsive with bootstrap.

Here is my current menu I am trying to make it collapse and presently it just disappears and doesn't show the the icon (3 lines in a box). Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?     Okay I have figured out the css wasn't allowing it appear as the colours were wrong. I've made it white and now it appears. However it's a little buggy it makes the menu appear next to the bottom then quickly moves it down. How do I make it fix this?

```
<div class="navbar-header">

<a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a></div
<div class="width-navigation table-cell table-right navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu-main-menu">
                        <li class="menu item"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li class="menu item"><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                        <li class="menu item"><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                        <li class="menu item"><a href="#">test3</a></li>         
                    </ul>         
</div>


@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
```

}

Comment: Check out the docs for the default [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) structure.

Comment: I've had a look and I think mine matches up pretty well. The only issue I have now is there is a delay when opening the menu when it's collapsed, it appears up high then goes down. Any ideas? When I test in bootply it's fine. :/

Comment: Fixed it, found some css that was bugging it out.

Comment: You have an un-closed div tag for `.navbar-header` too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your navbar structure is wrong.

Check the docs in: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Are you calling jQuery correctly?

Don't forget:
1st: Call jquery.min.js
2nd: Call bootstrap.min.js

Call the scripts AFTER your code.

PS: I like call these files before  tag.